# How to find a specific regular expression patern but exclude the middle character

Tags: regex

my testsentence is for example 'hello random-word testing'

I would like to find the regular expression to extract 'random word' but explude the dash ('-')

I tried [a-z]+[^-][a-z]+, but this also selects the words in front and at the end

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
([a-z]+)[-]([a-z]+)
```

At that point `$1` and `$2` will contain your words. Alternatively

```
([a-z]+[-][a-z]+)
```

At that point, just do a replace on `$1` for `'-' -> ' '`